# Parse SNMP MIB Files to generate a list of Devices and OID

Tags: python, parsing, snmp, oid, mib

I am processing a large number of SNMP MIB Files and from them creating a dictionary of devices and their respective ID, in the form "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.694":"catalyst296024".

I am currently using Mibble for the MIB parsing part as after trying out other apps/modules, I found it to be the ideal. Then I am using python to work on the data.

My problem is that I only need the "device name & OID". Since when I parse I am getting all the OID data I have not yet managed to find a way to intelligently identify the device and ignore the rest of the stuff. (Short of physically looking at the data line by line)

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest things to do would be to use Net-SNMP's `mib2c` program, which will let you write a quick output based on a set of MIB objects.  See [it's wiki page](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Mib2c) for details on how to write mib2c scripts.

Also, you could simply parse the output of a command, like [snmptranslate](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptranslate) that will print a tree structure output (use `-Tp`) that is likely easier to parse than the MIB file itself.

Comment: Hi Wes, thanks for the reply. I already have the MIB export. My problem is identifying the actual device name from all the OIDs in the exported MIB. I mean in one case, you may have the device directly under the enterprises.organization node, in others there can be a group, or something else.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question then.  But if it's what I think it is (now), there is no wonderful way to determine what the device is from MIB objects.  Some devices do report what it is "somewhere", and others do not.  It's really quite annoying!

Comment: Yes, that was the question. Ah ok, thanks for your help, appreciated!